# 'IntegerField' object has no attribute 'value_from_datadict' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-forms

**I'm having a problem with my IntigerField in Django forms:
Getting error:IntegerField' object has no attribute 'value_from_datadict'**

**This is mine forms.py:**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = ('task_title','task_discription','task_category','recommended_tools','budget')
    widgets = {
        'task_title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'task_discription': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'task_category': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'recommended_tools': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'budget': forms.IntegerField(min_value=10, max_value=10000000),
    }
```

Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import ListView,DetailView, CreateView
from .models import Post, TaskCategory
from .forms import PostForm
 
class AddPost(CreateView):
   model = Post
   form_class = PostForm
   template_name = 'add_post.html'
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import AddPost

urlpatterns = [
     path('AddPost/', AddPost.as_view(), name = 'add_post')
     ]
```

**models.py file:**
**I'm trying to insert post into database, using django forms, but I'm always getting error from intiger, when I click on submit, noting is happening, and always getting same error**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
class TaskCategory(models.Model):
category_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
def __str__(self):
return self.category_title

class Post(models.Model):
task_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
task_discription = models.CharField(max_length=250)
task_category = models.ForeignKey(TaskCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
recommended_tools = models.CharField(max_length=250)
budget = models.IntegerField(default=0)
def __str__(self):
return self.task_title + ' | ' + self.task_discription + ' | ' + 
str(self.task_category) + ' | ' + self.recommended_tools + ' | ' + 
str(self.budget)

def get_absolute_url(self)       
return reverse('post_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

Comment: can you show your models.py ?

Comment: Please post it as a Question. Because Nobody can understand this in Comment.

Comment: @Progam I think this error is in task_category.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `forms.Select` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
from django import forms

from .models import Post

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    task_category = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(doc.uid, doc.name) for doc in Document.objects.all()])   #your choices data...

    class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = ('task_title','task_discription','task_category','recommended_tools','budget')
    widgets = {
        'task_title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'task_discription': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'task_category': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'recommended_tools': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'budget': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'min': '0', 'class': 'yourClass', 'id': 'blah'}),
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You use **the form field [forms.IntegerField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/#integerfield)** for **"widgets"** which is wrong:

```py
widgets = {         
    # ...           # Wrong
    'budget': forms.IntegerField(min_value=10, max_value=10000000),
}
```

So, instead, you need to use **the widget [forms.NumberInput()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/widgets/#numberinput)** for **"widgets"** which is correct:

```py
widgets = {
    # ...           # Correct
    'budget': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'min': '10', 'max': '10000000'}),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set attribute in IntegerField just like another fields

like this one:

```
class TimerForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
   model = Timer
   fields=['hours']
   widgets = {
       'hours': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'min': '0', 'class': 'yourClass', 'id': 'blah'}),
}
```